# Show / Hide plugin is showing but not hiding content onclick?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins, hidden

I am using [this](http://papermashup.com/jquery-show-hide-plugin/) plugin. It works fine when I click on the link to show the hidden div, but it can't close when I click it again. Also, I'm using this for multiple divs and it again it toggles just fine, (meaning to say when I click on another link the current div gets replaced with the hidden div i just clicked) but again, it can't close.

Here is the script I'm using:

```
(function ($) {
$.fn.showHide = function (options) {

    //default vars for the plugin
    var defaults = {
        speed: 1000,
        easing: '',
        changeText: 0,
        showText: 'Show',
        hideText: 'Hide'

    };
    var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

    $(this).click(function () { 

         $('.toggleDiv').slideUp(options.speed, options.easing);    
         // this var stores which button you've clicked
         var toggleClick = $(this);
         // this reads the rel attribute of the button to determine which div id to toggle
         var toggleDiv = $(this).attr('data-link');
         // here we toggle show/hide the correct div at the right speed and using which easing effect
         $(toggleDiv).slideToggle(options.speed, options.easing, function() {
         // this only fires once the animation is completed
         if(options.changeText==1){
         $(toggleDiv).is(":visible") ? toggleClick.text(options.hideText) : toggleClick.text(options.showText);
         }
          });

      return false;

    });

};
})(jQuery);
```

The script included in my index:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.show_hide').showHide({           
    speed: 1000, 
    easing: '',
    changeText: 0, 
    showText: 'View',
    hideText: 'Close'

}); 
});
```

And my HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="show_hide" data-link="#hiddencontent"> Open hidden content </a>
<div id="hiddencontent" class="toggleDiv" style="display: none;"> hello </div>
```

Anyone know how to fix this? I don't know if this is relevant but I am running this in [Colorbox's](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) inline content.

Comment: Try: `$('.toggleDiv').not(this).slideUp(options.speed, options.easing);`

Comment: Not working either. Now the divs are overlapping each other and none close.

Comment: What about providing a jsfiddle which replicates your issue??

Comment: My apologies, [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VXt27/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exclude target like this:

```
$('.toggleDiv').not(toggleDiv).slideUp(options.speed, options.easing);
```

### SEE complete DEMO

Comment: I just exclude the current clicked element target from matched set of elements, `$('.toggleDiv')`. Basically, your code was sliding up the already opened element and then sliding it down because of recalling `slideToggle()` on it

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var toggleDiv = $(toggleClick.attr('data-link'));
```

Comment: made an edit, didn't notice you already had the # sign in there